# changing sql JOIN Syntax to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, inner-join

There are two tables: Posts and Tags. There is another table called PostsTags having both id of Posts and Tags table. what is the corresponding LINQ for below SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Tags ON Posts.ID = Tags.ID
```

and how can I retrieve the value of both table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any navigational properties and you want to join the two collections in Linq you would get:

```
var result = from p in Posts
            join t in Tags on p.ID equals t.ID
            select new { Post = p, Tag = t };
```

Comment: Now, I got it and how can I get value from result in the view when var result is passed through controllers return View(result).

Comment: I've used var in this case because you are selecting an anonymous type. Anonymous types are automatically created by the compiler and are internal which means you can't pass them around. The most elegant would be to create your own result class with two properties (Post and Tag) or if you don't want that you could use the Tuple<,> class, but then you would lose semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding LINQ will look like that:

```
var posts = from p in context.Posts
            join t in context.Tags on p.ID equals t.ID
            select p;
```

However that query does not make much sense, since there is no any explicit connection between Posts IDs and Tags IDs.

If we are talking about LINQ to SQL generated context, than you can retrieve all pairs of posts and tags with this:

```
var postsTags = from pt in context.PostsTags
                select new {Post = pt.Post, Tag = pt.Tags};
```

Just like that. If there is a foreign key relation between two tables, LINQ handles all the job of getting the referenced object by itself.

However, if we are talking about some other LINQ (LINQ to Objects, LINQ to XML), than here is the query you need:

```
var postsTags = from pt in context.PostsTags
                join p in context.Posts on pt.PostID equals p.ID
                join t in context.Tags on pt.TagID equals t.ID
                select new {Post = p, Tag = t};
```

Comment: I have build table directly in sql server without creating class for model. There relation between Posts and Tags table that is created with PostsTag table which have ID of Posts and Tags. I have created relationship of tables by using VS 2010 tools.

Comment: If I understood your situation right, second or third options are what you need in this case - they select all pairs of Posts and Tags connected by PostsTags table.